# WebView from Unity3d Android is not shown

Tags: android, webview, unity-game-engine

I am trying to show a webview in unity3d from an Android Application.
The components of this test are:
Android library(has a method that i call for test purposes):

```
public void nonStaticMethod() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Non-static method was called from my android class");
        String url = "http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.ro/2014/02/road-to-setup-and-create-first-appium.html";
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "URL: " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        webView = new WebView(mContext);
        Log.d("Interstitialactivity", "webView: " + webView);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "webView: " + webView, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        webView.loadUrl(url); // webview is not null

    }
```

Mono code from class:

```
using (AndroidJavaClass javaInterClass = new AndroidJavaClass("mypackage.MyActivity")) {
            if (javaInterClass != null) {
            Debug.Log ("MyActivity class is NOT null");

            try {
                Debug.Log ("before my activity");
                javaInterClass.Call ("nonStaticMethod");
                Debug.Log ("after my activity");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug.Log ("exception");
                Console.WriteLine (e);
            }

        } else {
            Debug.Log ("MyActivity class is null");
        }
    }
```

From the above code i can see the android class is not null, but the webview( from this "javaInterClass.Call ("nonStaticMethod");") is not shown.

Do i have to add a plugin in unity3d for supporting webview? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open webview over Unity's UI you need an activity or you need to override unity's activity otherwise you can try this

`Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);`

but it work same as Unity's Application.LoadUrl(url)

Comment: Hello, my android activity extends UnityPlayerActivity. Added the above code but does not want to log anything or to show. What object (and more important) in what part: android or unity3d should i call to have the LoadUrl(url). Thank you for your time

Comment: If you re extending your activity, I'm using [this code](http://pastebin.com/Kb3ZZbm5), you can try, it places webview over Unity's UI. By the way it's not Application.LoadUrl(url) I m sorry its  Application.OpenUrl(url), you can call it anywhere you want from a script inside Unity.

Comment: i can use Application.OpenURL ("http://unity3d.com/"); and will use this if i can get a variable from the android project part. Thx. I will set your answer as correct, for it helped me.